# Caesar cipher in Java with recursion?

Tags: java, encryption, recursion

So, I'm trying to come up with a way to do an encryption/decryption of a caesar cipher (where you take in a value, then shift the letters that many times along the alphabet, for example, if the key was 3, then a would become d, b would be e, and c would be f and so on) but I need to use recursion, rather than iteration. Here's what I have so far, but it's only encrypting the very last character, and outputting "Encrypted - w" which doesn't make sense to me.

```
public class Driver {

static String encrypted = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Encrypted - " + cipher("encrypt", 3));

}

public static String cipher(String str, int i){
    char ch = str.charAt(0);
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
            ch = (char) ('a' + (ch - 'a' + i) %26);
            output.append(ch);
            return output.toString(); 
    }
    else{
        return cipher(str.substring(1),i);

    }


}

}
```

Comment: You are returning just the encrypted "tail" in your else. Need to combine it with the head.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so...but what do you mean by the head? How would I alter that?

Comment: `return cipher(str.substring(1),i);`  This returns just the end of the string. You need to think how to combine this with the not-end part to get the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Hey in this logic you are doing encryption for last letter only. You have to do it for all the letters. and as @Thilo rightly said you have to take care of head also.
The working solution would be like this :

```
public static String cipher(String str, int i) {
    char ch = str.charAt(0);
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    ch = (char) ('a' + (ch - 'a' + i) % 26);
    output.append(ch);

    if (str.length() > 1) {
        output.append(cipher(str.substring(1), i));
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```